# Function to test variable type or throw in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to have a function to test if a class variable is not `null` and use it in follow up function calls. But got TS complaints. Encapsulate this validate function because I need to call it in many of my methods.

```
class A {
  point: Point | null
  validatePoint() {
    if (!this.point) throw new Error()
  }

  update(p: Point | null) {
    this.validatePoint()
    // ts complains this.point can be null
    doSomething(this.point)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Typescript 3.7 introduces [assertions in control flow analysis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695):

```
class A {
    point: Point | null = null;
    validatePoint(): asserts this is { point: Point} {
        if (!this.point) throw new Error()
    }

    update(p: Point | null) {
        this.validatePoint()
        // now ts is sure that this.point can't be null
        doSomething(this.point)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gSwHbCgXigbwL4G4BQ+AJhAMYA2AhgE7QBmArkqcAnElEXAMpwC2EYAAtkAcwAUYRCgBcsacACUcgG6IiBfBUoBnHVACCWfFFNQpyYHPiWoAHyhIG5cukfPyBM1BWVyCIkpgCBsUcWUoXR0IamB9YQR9RKxzBWsFbGNvbwQ6KHEAQgSdADoLFEUoYWo4AHdHCHqAUWoa6nCTM2xCbwYwQODJdNsHJxdKzE7sqpFS338BkIUO6dMAejXHOqqk-R0GWhmgmcSyhShSSiQAclQAI2gx8insrl4BBKQJYrPLRRfutggA)

Comment: This is awesome! I tried it in playground it it works perfectly, but somehow in my local I got `cannot find name asserts`. My ts version is 3.7.2.

Comment: The error comes from typescript compiler or somewhere else? (e.g. ide, eslint)

Comment: it is from ide.

Comment: I also tried to run it in jest, and got `Unexpected token, expected "{"` regarding this function

Comment: It works fine of you compile with tsc, but looks like ides still not recognize this syntax :/. Regrading jest - I guess you need to update `babel/typescript` if you're using it

Comment: Thanks! I ended up with a different implementation. Upvote for a valid approach.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a type guard instead, and throw in `update` instead of `validatePoint`:

```
class A {
    point: Point | null;
    validatePoint(p: Point | null): p is Point {
        return Boolean(this.point);
    }
    update(p: Point | null) {
        if (!this.validatePoint(this.point)) {
            throw new Error();
        }
        doSomething(this.point);
    }
}
```

But using a separate method for something like this seems a bit overkill:

```
update(p: Point | null) {
    if (this.point === null) {
        throw new Error();
    }
    doSomething(this.point);
}
```

If you have to put it in a separate function, then another option is for `validatePoint` to return the validated point (since this sort of thing can't be used to narrow the type of a parent object IIRC):

```
class A {
    point: Point | null;
    validatePoint() {
        if (this.point === null) {
            throw new Error();
        }
        return this.point;
    }
    update(p: Point | null) {
        const validatedPoint = this.validatePoint();
        doSomething(validatedPoint);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for an TS instruction to let it know `point` can not be `null`. I have many functions call `validatePoint`, otherwise I won't need to encapsulate it into a function.

Comment: Thanks! upvote for a valid approach, still looking for a direction if is this in the road map of TS feature list.

Answer (score 0):

You should be explicitly checking for null using an `if(this.point === null)` statement. Although I don't think you need a separate method for this, it seems a bit overkill.

Comment: I have many methods needs to `validatePoint`. That's why I want to make it a function.

Answer (score 0):

In `update`, you validate if `this.point` is null.

If `this.point` is null, an error is thrown and `doSomething` is not invoked.
If `this.point` is not null, that means `this.point` is `Point` type.

So it is not possible that `this.point` is null, when `doSomething` is invoked. That's why TS complains like that.

Comment: what you said is right in run time. `it is not possible that this.point is null, when doSomething is invoked`. But TS complains *because* it thinks `this.point` can be `null`. That why I want to tell ts compiler is can not be `null`.

Comment: Yeah, but again I need to have it in all my caller functions which kind of violate my encapsulate in one function idea.